# Cant see scope claims in Azure Ad OAuth-protected api

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I have a problem with a my api that is protected with "Azure AD OAuth 2.0". We want to give our associates access to our api (without any end user interaction/approvals)

I once copied [this example](https://github.com/azureadquickstarts/appmodelv2-nativeclient-dotnet) and last time I tried it I could, from my api-code, see the claims sent from our clients. Now I cant anymore.

.

This is my setup in azure

[image]

.

This is what I see on the ClaimsPrincipal.Current
.
[image]

I expected to see the two scope claims. What Im I doing wrong or how can I start finding the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply put because delegated permissions apply when an app calls an API on behalf of a user.
There is no user in your scenario, so only application permissions apply.

In this scenario you should define application permissions and grant them to your app.
You can then find their values in the `roles` claim.

Here is my article on the subject: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Here is an example permission defined in the manifest of an API:

```
{
  "appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "Application"
    ],
    "displayName": "Read all todo items",
    "id": "f8d39977-e31e-460b-b92c-9bef51d14f98",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "description": "Allow the application to read all todo items as itself.",
    "value": "Todo.Read.All"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Juunas, Ive lost count on how many times youve saved my bacon on this Azure AD-stuff!. This works like a charm! Thanks again :)